# HttpListenerException On Using Microsoft Login

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-appservice

I am using MS Auth to login the user for my .NET Core 6 web app hosted in Azure app service. Getting following when trying to open MS UI in browser for authentication.

```
An HttpListenerException occurred while listening on http://localhost:49299/ for the system browser to complete the login. Possible cause and mitigation: the app is unable to listen on the specified URL; run 'netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1' from the Admin command prompt. Access is denied.
```

I even tried proving the access, but getting Access Denied error.
[image]

Comment: In the `App registration` have you added the deployed App under the `Redirect URI` ?

Comment: @Harshitha I tried this but still the same error. I have added my Web App URI in the Redirect URIs of the App registration.

Comment: Could you please share the Screenshot once.

Comment: Are you getting the error when running with `localhost` or the deployed app ?

Comment: I am running the app deployed in Azure App service - running the app in local environment works fine

Comment: You need to add the `ClientID` in the `Application settings` of the deployed App.

Comment: I have already added that in the Configuration section of the deployed app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252403/discussion-between-harshitha-and-amit-sharma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iam able to login the user with `MSAuth` for the web app hosted in Azure app service.

***Check the below steps:***

Register the Application in `AAD`.

[image]

- We can download the sample code for same from the `Registered App`.
- Navigate to the `AAD` => `App registrations` => Your `registered App` => `Quickstart` => click on the `Web application`

[image]

- Select `ASP.NET Core`, you will see the below screen.
- Click on the `Manage this change for me` => Make updates => `Download the code sample`.
- 

[image]

***My `appsettings.json` :***

```cs
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "****.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "**************",
    "TenantId": "********",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

***My `Program.cs` :***

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI(); 

var app = builder.Build();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
//app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
//{
//    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
//        name: "default",
//        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
//    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
//});
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

***My `.csproj` :***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***My `Redirect URI`:***

[image]

***Output:***
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed steps. Since my web app is calling my APIs, I need to create an access token (JWT), so I had to do some customizations after user logs in. I have used graph API to acquire this token.